# Excel and regional settings

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

Is there any way to disable excel to read regional settings for date cell?
Currently present format in cell is different for display and edit, like it is present below:

[image]

Comment: Your regional settings are set to mm/dd/yyyy, but you're then formatting the cell to dd/mm/yyyy. Choose one, but change either to make them match.

Comment: Yes, but can I force excel to not read regional settings?

Comment: Could you change the regional settings for the workbook with `Application.International(xlCountrySetting)`?

Comment: If Excel would be forced to "not read regional settings" how do you expect Excel to format dates? Or (in other words) Excel needs to know how to format dates. If you prevent it from reading your regional settings then what's the alternative? Do not format dates at all? Default to an international date format (what ever that might be)? You'd have to set the date format for Excel to something different than the regional setting. Tom just provided one. Another approach might be here: https://superuser.com/q/730371/418281

Comment: @Tom Can You provide some example how can I do it? I do not know enough excel

Comment: I'm not sure you can change it at the Workbook level, but perhaps it is possible (as per @Tom's suggestion) at the Application level. Which begs the question, why not just change the Region.

Comment: @CLR Sorry what I meant was to change it on the activate and reset it on the deactivate of the workbook to whatever it was before

Comment: @CLR - because I want to have one format for each user which will have the file - independently of regional settings (display and edit of cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the folling into a module:
For this to work we need to store the users initial setting in a public variable. This will need to be put into a `Module` not an `Object`

```
Option Explicit
Public InternationalDateSetting As XlApplicationInternational
```

Then put this into the `ThisWorkbook` object. When the user opens the Workbook it will set the users setting to the public variable. Then in this when the user deactivates the workbook (i.e. changes to another workbook or another program) it will reset the users setting back to default and it will then change it to your custom setting when the user activates the workbook. In doing this it will control the Application settings but be workbook specific

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    InternationalDateSetting = Application.International(xlMDY)
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    '' Please look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840213.aspx for all settings
    '' Set to true for month-day-year order, false for day-month-year
    Application.International(xlMDY) = True
    '' Or uncomment and use:
    '' 0 = month-day-year
    '' 1 = day-month-year
    '' 2 = year-month-day
    '' You will also need to change the Workbook_Open and Workbook_Deactivate from 'xlMDY' to 'xlDateOrder'

    ' Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 0
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.International(xlMDY) = InternationalDateSetting
End Sub
```

Comment: can You provide some example excel file via link to hosted file?

Comment: I tried your answer exactly as you typed , But I got error "Object Required" @ this line **Application.International(xlMDY) = True** in workbook_Activate. Please help